# How do I get the number of results in a webpage with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I am new to python and Selenium and I am trying to automatize a process that is copying a search query from excel, introducing it in a specific textbox and look for number of results under the query. Once I have the number of results, I want to copy this number in excel again. I could build almost all the code but I don't know how to get the number of results given by my search. In other words, I would like to extract the number 15 (I would also be happy with the whole text 'Headlines 1 - 15')which is contained in the following line of html code:

> 

```html
<span class="resultsBar" data-hits="15">Headlines 1 - 15 of 15</span>
```

I tryed many different things, i.e.:

```html
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/span[2]").getattribute("data-hits")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/span[2]").getattribute("value")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/span[2]").getText()
```

but none of this worked.
Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks in advance,
S.

Comment: Can you share the url for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `get_attribute("data-hits")` and following `xpath`.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='resultsBar']").get_attribute("data-hits")
```